# How can I get the exit code or exit status after finish a robotium test on the command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, robotium, exit-code

Now I wrote a batch script to run the command like:

```
adb -s emulator-5556 shell am instrument -e class com.example.test.locationListTest -w com.example.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRun
```

Then at the console I get results like `FAILURE!!! Tests run: 5 fail:4` or `OK`.

I use `if errorlevel 0` to determine the upper command, but it gives me 0 no matter the upper command gives me,  OK or FAILURE.

I need to do this in batch script like this:

```
if(adb -s emulator-5556 shell ..... test.InstrumentationTestRun == SUCCESS )
do (.........)
else (.........)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "adb=adb -s emulator-5556 shell am instrument -e class com.example.test.locationListTest -w com.example.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRun"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('%adb%^|find /i "Ok"') do (
  if not errorlevel 1 ( 
         Echo Success 
  ) else (
         echo Failure
  )
)
```

This way, errorlevel will work because it's coming from Find.

Answer (score 1):

`if errorlevel 0` is always true.

You need to use `if not errorlevel 1` when you use that style of line for testing.

Answer (score 1):

What about something simple, like:

```
adb -s emulator-5556 shell am instrument -e class com.example.test.locationListTest -w com.example.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRun | grep "Failures"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "## TEST FAILED ##"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than doing it via adb you can instead run your instumentation tests with gradle.

Here is an example bash script to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD="./gradlew connectedAndroidTest"
$CMD
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ]; then
 echo "failed $CMD"
 exit 1
fi
exit 0
```